# Replacing Capacitor

Tags: electrical, hvac, replacement

Wanted to know what capacitor is compatible with mfc 080 241k capacitor
my window ac stopped working when I plugged it up. I blew a fuse but noticed the capacitor next to it was fried.

Comment: what does the label on the capacitor says

Comment: Can you post photos showing the dead capacitor in context please?